# Automatically pull code in server from github

Tags: php, laravel, continuous-delivery

I am developing a laravel application and have a test server setup to show the demo to client. How i get the code in server is I push the code to github and login to server and pull the code there and run.
Is there an automated way of doing this? I looked at continuous integration/delivery and it seemed to be dealing with testing the code?

Comment: Use CircleCI or there are open source solutions on GitHub too. But CircleCI should be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it by using webhook
To get git pull to run on the server every time there is a commit, can be achieved by using Webhooks.

On GitLab go to Settings -> Integrations

Enter a url to your server and a file to handle the webhook for this tutorial I will create a file called gitlab.php to the url will be

```
http://example.com/gitlab.php
```

Enter your url ensure push events is tickets and click Add Webook.

Now head over to your server and create a php file on the server.

touch gitlab.php (you can name it anything but it much match the webhook on GitLab)
As the file created won’t have the right permissions change it with chmod

```
chmod 644 gitlab.php
```

Now edit the file with vim:

vi gitlab.php
Press i to go into edit mode

Type:

git pull
Then press escape to go into read mode then save and exit by pressing : then type wq and enter.

By using backticks in the file the server will treat the file as a bash script.

Alternatively, you can use system_exec(‘git pull’)

Now make a change on GitLab and the change will be pushed to your server automatically.

Comment: You need to avoid force push with this approach. Or the `git pull` command would fail. Also the web server need to have full permission to change files and folders where the source code is.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using rsync

1) You could `rsync` the code directly from your instance to the customers server:/path/

Example:

```
rsync -avz yourwebfolder/ user@customerserverip:/var/www/
```

#### Using CI/CD

2) You can also push to Github or Gitlab and have a CI/CD which may run tests, and if they pass, to push directly to the customer's server, (for which you would need to setup ssh keys between the git build and the customer's server)

Testing of the code is always optional but also always preferable. So you can do a CI/CD without any testing..

#### How To CI/CD

If your repository is on Github go to it and then click on `Actions`, and there you can setup workflows.. There are tutorials online on how to set it up, here's one [exampe tutorial](https://medium.com/@michaelekpang/creating-a-ci-cd-pipeline-using-github-actions-b65bb248edfe).

Gitlab has similar CI/CD section, where you can create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in the root of the project, and add the instructions there.

Comment: Thanks. which CI/CD tool do i use for this?

Answer (score -1):

Create an SSH key in the server and add that the public key to github. Once you have done that, you do not need to login to push or pull.

Creating public and private key
http://lunar.lyris.com/help/lm_help/12.0/Content/generating_public_and_private_keys.html

Adding keys to github
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account